# using angulartics in my hybird app, but the real time report does not have data

Tags: google-analytics, angulartics

I want to use GA, and in my application I use angulartics, my code as follows：

```
     <script src="./js/angulartics.js"></script>
<script src="./js/angulartics-ga-cordova.js"></script>

<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function()
    { (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)}
    ,i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-71273816-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav buttons', 4);
</script>

 var module = ons.bootstrap('my-app', ['onsen','ngSanitize','ngCookies','ngStorage', 'angulartics','angulartics.google.analytics.cordova']);
```

But in my real time report, there is no data, but I can see information at my GA Debugger as follows：

```
Running command: ga("create", "UA-xxxxxx-1", "auto")
analytics_debug.js:9 Creating new tracker: t0
analytics_debug.js:9 Auto cookieDomain found: "monaca.mobi"
analytics_debug.js:9 Running command: ga("send", "event", "button", "click", "nav buttons", 4)
analytics_debug.js:9 
Sent beacon:
xxxxxx
analytics_debug.js:9 _j1              (&jid) 
analytics_debug.js:9 adSenseId        (&a)   xxxxxx
analytics_debug.js:9 apiVersion       (&v)   1
analytics_debug.js:9 clientId         (&cid) xxxxxx
analytics_debug.js:9 encoding         (&de)  UTF-8
analytics_debug.js:9 eventAction      (&ea)  click
analytics_debug.js:9 eventCategory    (&ec)  button
analytics_debug.js:9 eventLabel       (&el)  nav buttons
analytics_debug.js:9 eventValue       (&ev)  4
analytics_debug.js:9 flashVersion     (&fl)  20.0 r0
analytics_debug.js:9 hitType          (&t)   event
analytics_debug.js:9 javaEnabled      (&je)  0
analytics_debug.js:9 language         (&ul)  en-us
analytics_debug.js:9 location         (&dl)  xxxxxx
analytics_debug.js:9 referrer         (&dr)  https://xxxxxx
analytics_debug.js:9 screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
analytics_debug.js:9 screenResolution (&sr)  1366x768
analytics_debug.js:9 trackingId       (&tid) UA-xxxxxx-1
analytics_debug.js:9 viewportSize     (&vp)  320x568
```

Anybody knows the reason？